# Can a class use an __init__ method that would create other instances of the same class?

Tags: python, class

Here is what I would like to achieve. I am trying to read a tree (let's say a folder structure).
I would like to define a generic node in this tree and the initialization of this object should trigger the tree traversing like below

```
class node():
    def __init__(self, name, parent, children=[]):
        self.name = name
        self.parent = parent
        self.children = children

        nodes = "code to find children"

        for child in nodes:
            children.append(node(childname, self.name))

def main():
    Tree = node("root", "")
```

When this initial object is initialized it should contain the complete tree. This is for python. Would this work?

Comment: This should work as any other recursion, i.e. if there's a terminating condition.

Comment: Are you sure it's a Tree. Directed and Acyclic?  If there's a cycle, you'll see a recursion error

Comment: As an aside, it should be `def __init__(self, name, parent, children=[]):`

Comment: @tdelaney: oops, that's on me. Look at the first revision, there were many more issues.

Comment: Yes it is a tree, a folder structure, no soft links

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can reference the class in the `__init__` method, and you can use it to create more instances of the same class. Your approach works.

Do be careful with the `children=[]` default argument; that will create a *shared list*, stored once for that method. See ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument) for why that is going to trip you up and how to avoid that issue.

Comment: thanks a lot guys, and I am sorry for the mistakes in the initial post. I am not a programmer... :-) I am learning this art.